# Tikz fill area enclosed by cycle

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths, draw, tikz-path

It is in tikz possible to fill area inside a cycle, right?

I am having issues with it and I can't figure out what I am messing up:

```
\documentclass[center]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\node[circle, fill, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (a) at (3,0,0) {};
\node[left of = a] {$a$};
\node[circle, fill, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (b) at (5,0,4) {};
\node[left of = b] {$b$};
\node[circle, fill, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (apb) at (8,0,1) {};
\node[right of = apb] {$a + b$};

\draw[->, very thin] (a) -- node[below] {$i_1$} (apb);
\draw[->, very thin] (b) -- node[below] {$i_2$} (apb);

\node[circle, fill, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (fa) at (3,3,0) {};
\node[right of = fa, circle, minimum size = 6cm] {};
\node[left of = fa] {$f(a)$};
\node[circle, fill, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (fb) at (5,3,4) {};
\node[right of = fb, circle, minimum size = 3cm] {};
\node[left of = fb] {$f(b)$};
\node[circle, fill, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (fapb) at (8,3,1) {};
\node[right of = fapb, circle, minimum size = 3cm] {};
\node[right of = fapb] {$f(a + b)$};

\draw[very thin, dashed, blue, ->] (a) -- (fa);
\draw[very thin, dashed, blue, ->] (b) -- (fb);
\draw[very thin, dashed, blue, ->] (apb) -- (fapb);


\draw[very thin, ->] (fa) -- node[below] {$j_1$} (fapb);
\draw[very thin, ->] (fb) -- node[below] {$j_2$} (fapb);


\fill[red] (b) -- (apb) -- (a) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the bottom two arrows are red, but I want the triangle between the bottom three point to be red. The triangle is described by the path `(b) -- (apb) -- (a) --cycle` however. So... what is problem?

Comment: `a`, `b` and `apb` are nodes. They have a size. The red lines connect only the borders of the nodes. You could use `(b.center)--(apb.center)--(a.center)--cycle`.

Comment: I didn't realise that my vote to close as duplicate would be binding.  Please do check to see if that question answers yours.  If not, please do edit your question to explain why and it'll get re-opened.

Comment: It does answer it, as well as esdd's comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[center]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\node[circle, fill,red, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (a) at (3,0,0) {};
\node[left of = a] {$a$};
\node[circle, fill,red, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (b) at (5,0,4) {};
\node[left of = b] {$b$};
\node[circle, fill,red, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (apb) at (8,0,1) {};
\node[right of = apb] {$a + b$};

\draw[->, very thin,red] (a) -- node[below] {\color{black}$i_1$} (apb);
\draw[->, very thin,red] (b) -- node[below] {\color{black}$i_2$} (apb);

\node[circle, fill, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (fa) at (3,3,0) {};
\node[right of = fa, circle, minimum size = 6cm] {};
\node[left of = fa] {$f(a)$};
\node[circle, fill, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (fb) at (5,3,4) {};
\node[right of = fb, circle, minimum size = 3cm] {};
\node[left of = fb] {$f(b)$};
\node[circle, fill, inner sep = 0, minimum size = 2mm] (fapb) at (8,3,1) {};
\node[right of = fapb, circle, minimum size = 3cm] {};
\node[right of = fapb] {$f(a + b)$};

\draw[very thin, dashed, blue, ->] (a) -- (fa);
\draw[very thin, dashed, blue, ->] (b) -- (fb);
\draw[very thin, dashed, blue, ->] (apb) -- (fapb);


\draw[very thin, ->] (fa) -- node[below] {$j_1$} (fapb);
\draw[very thin, ->] (fb) -- node[below] {$j_2$} (fapb);


\fill[red] (b) -- (apb) -- (a) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]